# Multi-Tenant Authentication Strategy w/ JWTs

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I am creating a multi-tenant'd ASP.NET Core application where users can belong to one or many tenants.  When a user tries to authenticate, I'd like to generate a JWT with userId and tenantId as claims so that APIs can use these values instead of them having to be passed in every time via route or body object.  Currently if a user is associated to only one tenant, then it's easy, I just generate the JWT tenantId claim with the only one they are associated with.  But if the user is associated to more than one then what would my strategy be?

For clarity from a UI perspective imagine a standard email/password login form.  If associated to one tenant, take you to that tenants landing page.  If associated to multiple tenants, then go to a tenant select screen.

Currently I am thinking that I will have two "types" of JWT tokens, a UserToken and a TenantUserToken.  UserToken would essentially just be userId of a successfully authenticated email/password which could then be used to hit a few endpoints such as seeing what leagues the userId of the UserToken is associated with, or do general user management stuff that is not associated to any specific tenant.  TenantUserToken would be the fully filled out token with tenantId and will be the main authenticator for majority of tenant action endpoints.  The following is a generalization of what I am thinking:

```
AppToken AuthenticateUser(string email, string password, int? tenantId)
{
    var user = ValidateUser(email, password);

    if(user == null){
        //return error "email and/or password incorrect"
    }

    if(tenantId != null){
        bool valid = ValidateTenantUser(user, tenantId);

        if(valid){
            //return error "user does not have access to tenant"
        }else{
            //return TenantUserToken
        }
     }

     if(user.associatedTenants.count != 1){
         //return UserToken
     }else{
         //return TenantUserToken
     }
}

public class AppToken{
    public string Token;
    public TokenType TokenType; //enum of TenantUserToken or UserToken
}
```

I very well could be overthinking this, but I've been spinning on it long enough I thought I would reach out and see if anyone else had a thought?

Comment: You could store all of the tenant ids in the token (if they fit) and store an additional claim that is the active tenant id. Then switching the tenant of course requires generating a new token. Just an idea :)

Comment: @juunas I've considered something like this too.  By storing the available tenants on the token I would also be saving myself a trip to the DB to get the tenants list as well, but like you mentioned anytime I would want to assign an active tenant I'd be generating a new token.

Comment: Use a cookie for the current tenant.

Comment: Hi Ben, what solution did you end up with? We are facing the same issue and were thinking of issuing a new token when the user changes to another tenant. Thanks!

Comment: @lucbas I ended up building my application around the context of a single "current selected tenant", and then issued a new token when the user changes tenant, and I've been happy with the result.